# JavaScript local storage value NaN

Tags: javascript, html, localhost, local-storage, nan

My problem is the JavaScript Error NaN. Everything works perfectly in my LocalHost (file: ///), but as soon as I upload it, it says "NaN" everywhere. I don't understand what could be the cause, this is my first project with JavaScript.

I left out a lot of the HTML code, but that is also explained in the JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<div class="coinsdisplay">
    <input id="coins" type="text" disabled name="" value="0" class="coinInput">
</div>
<div class="cps">
    <p id="cps">0 Coins/s</p>
</div>

<script src="public/js/main.js"></script>

<script>
  window.onload= loadGame();
</script>
```

JS:

```
var coincount = 0;
var autoClick = 0;
var computer = 0;
var multiplier = 1;

// Single Click
function addCoin() {
  coincount = coincount + 1
  update()
}

// Updater
function update() {
  document.getElementById('coins').value = coincount;
  document.getElementById('cps').innerHTML = (((autoClick) + (computer*2))*multiplier) + " Coins/s";
  //AutoClicker
  document.getElementById('amountAutoClick').innerHTML = autoClick;
  document.getElementById('cosAutoClick').innerHTML = ((autoClick+1) * 12) + " Coins";
  //Computer
  document.getElementById('amountComputer').innerHTML = computer;
  document.getElementById('cosComputer').innerHTML = ((computer+1) * 15) + " Coins";
}

function timer() {
  coincount = coincount + autoClick;
  coincount = coincount + computer*2;
  update()
}
setInterval(timer, 1000)

// AutoClicker
function buyAutoClick() {
  if (coincount >= ((autoClick+1) * 12)) {
      coincount = coincount - ((autoClick+1) * 12);
      autoClick = autoClick + 1;
      update()
  }
}

// Computer
function buyComputer() {
  if (coincount >= ((computer+1) * 100)) {
      coincount = coincount - ((computer+1) * 50);
      computer = computer + 1;
      update()
  }
}

// SaveGame
function saveGame() {
  localStorage.setItem("coincount", coincount);
  localStorage.setItem("autoClick", autoClick);
  localStorage.setItem("computer", computer);
}
setInterval(saveGame, 1000)

function loadGame() {
  coincount = localStorage.getItem("coincount");
  coincount = parseInt(coincount);
  autoClick = localStorage.getItem("autoClick");
  autoClick = parseInt(autoClick);
  computer = localStorage.getItem("computer");
  computer = parseInt(computer);
  update()
}
```

I hope someone can help me, I wish you all a nice day.

Comment: You need `window.onload=loadGame;` or `window.addEventListener("load",loadGame)` without the `()`

Comment: is the end of the html file? or is that decide?

Comment: Does not matter since it executes after the page has loaded if you do it correctly

Answer (score 0):

do you call the function `loadGame` before the `saveGame` function? If so, the issue is probably that there is not yet anything saved in the localStorage. So `localStorage.getItem("something")` just returns `null`, and the `parseInt()` converts it into `NaN`. Make sure that you're localStorage is filled, or that you have default values like so (notice the  `|| 0`):

```
function loadGame() {
  coincount = localStorage.getItem("coincount") || 0;
  coincount = parseInt(coincount);
  autoClick = localStorage.getItem("autoClick") || 0;
  autoClick = parseInt(autoClick);
  computer = localStorage.getItem("computer") || 0;
  computer = parseInt(computer);
  update()
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work

Comment: @byte are you sure that the items in your localStorage do not contain invalid entries? It could be that they're already filled with `NaN` values because of previous runs

Comment: The issue is executing loadGame before anything because of the onload=loadGame()

Comment: @mplungjan how then? when you close the page and open it again, local storage should be called up.

Comment: if I block the local storage everything works (logically it doesn't save anything) it's because of the load but I don't understand how I should call up the storage when opening the page

Comment: To add an event handler you need to NOT execute it. The onload needs to execute it. When you do `window.onload=loadGame()`, the loadGame is executed before any of the other code has run. That means BEFORE `var coincount = 0;
var autoClick = 0;
var computer = 0;
var multiplier = 1;` your code will work with `window.onload=loadGame;`

Comment: If there is no values in localStorage, you need to set them to 0 like above

Comment: still does not work ...

I now have this at the end of the HTML file:

`<script src="public/js/main.js"></script>

  <script>
    window.onload= loadGame;
  </script>

  </body>
</html>`

is that right? 

and the first Lines in main.js is:
`var coincount = 0;
var autoClick = 0;
var computer = 0;
var multiplier = 1;`

Comment: I did it, set a timeout for loadGame ()